# Sorting Numbers in strings(array)

Tags: c#

how do i make my Comparer take account for negative numbers?
right know it sorts the numbers in my string, but it leaves out the minus("subtraction") sign. so i get the wrong output, see below the code.

```
public class MixedNumbersAndStringsComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        double xVal, yVal;

        if (double.TryParse(x, out xVal) && double.TryParse(y, out yVal))
            return xVal.CompareTo(yVal);
        else
            return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Actual output:

> 0 dag(e) 5 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 3 dag(e) 3 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> -4 dag(e) -17 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> -6 dag(e) -18 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 8 dag(e) 1 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 8 dag(e) 4 time(r) - xx - xx

expected output is:

> -6 dag(e) -18 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> -4 dag(e) -17 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 0 dag(e) 5 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 3 dag(e) 3 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 8 dag(e) 1 time(r) - xx - xx
>
> 8 dag(e) 4 time(r) - xx - xx

input data is:

```
TimeSpan tidtilbage = timeToExpire.GetTimeRemainingUntilPasswordExpiration("DOMAIN", p.SamAccountName);
TimeSpan under10 = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00, 00);
TimeSpan ikkeMinus10 = new TimeSpan(-10, 00, 00, 00);
if (tidtilbage < under10 && tidtilbage > ikkeMinus10)
{

    if (u.Enabled == true)
    {
        string lines = tidtilbage.Days + " dag(e) "
                + tidtilbage.Hours + " time(r)" + " - "
                + p.SamAccountName.ToUpper() + " - " + p.DisplayName + "\n\n";

        sorted[i] = lines;
        Array.Sort(sorted, new MixedNumbersAndStringsComparer());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little unclear; it's not obvious how the output relates to the program snippet. Do please amend.

Comment: Could you please, provide the expected behavior and the actual one? E.g. expected "-1" > "-5", actual "-1" < "-5"

Comment: And also, give us the real input values. Are you comparing "-4" and "-17" or  "-4 dag(e)" and  "-17 time(r)"?

Comment: And what is the input-data? Anyway: what do you think should `double.TryParse("0 dag(e) 5 time(r) - xx - xx", out xVal)` do?

Comment: hope that helps :-)

Comment: Not really. This question is an absolute mess.

Comment: Why don't you sort them first and then change to string?

Comment: iam not sure how to do that, when the timespan must be connected with the Accountname and the displayname collected from the AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems taht you're looking for *logical sorting* (i.e. treat *integers* within the string as *integers*: `"10"` > `"9"` when you sort logically, but `"10"` < `"9"` when you sort lexicographically). Quick and dirty (*interop*) implementation:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

public sealed class MixedNumbersAndStringsComparer : IComparer<string> {
  [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string left, string right);

  public int Compare(string left, string right) {
    return StrCmpLogicalW(left, right);
  }
}
```

You can even get rid of `IComparer<string>`:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string left, string right);
...

string[] data = ...;

Array.Sort(data, (left, right) => StrCmpLogicalW(left, right));
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the answer, when i try to implement the code, SafeNativeMethods does not exist in the current context, what do i need to make this work other than the using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: @Mathias Rønnow Nørtoft: I'm sorry for typo (I've dropped `SafeNativeMethods` class when simplifying my solution) it should be `return StrCmpLogicalW(left, right);`

Answer (score 1):

SafeNativeMethods is a class that you have to implement, if you want.
In this class, you have to add this code:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true)]
static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
```

However, in the Dmitry answer DllImport is already implemented in the same class. So you don't have to write "SafeNativeMethods".

Dmitry's correct code is:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

public sealed class MixedNumbersAndStringsComparer : IComparer<string> {
  [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string left, string right);

  public int Compare(string left, string right) {
    return MixedNumbersAndStringsComparer.StrCmpLogicalW(left, right); // or return StrCmpLogicalW(left, right);
  }
}
```

Hi.